# button.text will not change the button text c#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to use a `Click` event to change the button text, so once that button is clicked, it checks what its `Text` property is set to, and then follow the appropriate function. It *does* execute one of the functions but not the other, which of course is the **button text property updater**.

I tried changing its location in the event:

```
private void Button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (button3.Text == "Transparent") {
        button3.Text = "Black";
        this.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
        this.Opacity = 0.7;
        this.TransparencyKey = Color.LimeGreen;  
    }

    if(button3.Text == "Black") {
        button3.Text = "Transparent";
        this.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
        this.Opacity = 1.0;
        this.TransparencyKey = Color.LimeGreen;
        button3.Text = "Transparent";
    }
}
```

I expect it to change the button text on `Click` event.

Comment: You should learn to debug your own code and it will be clear immediately. First, you change the text from "Transparent" to "Black" and then immediately from "Black" to "Transparent" back again. You are missing an `else` there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `if{} else if{}`

```
if (button3.Text == "Transparent") {
    button3.Text = "Black";
    // your code....
} else if (button3.Text == "Black") {
    // your code
    button3.Text = "Transparent";
}
```

Because when you change it to black,  it instantly goes to your "if" statement that checks if it is black and changes it back.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try `button3.content` instead of `button3.text`. You also might need to convert it to a string before you test if it is equivalent to "Transparent" or "Black".

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few problems.

Your main issue is the `if/else if` block. It calls your first if block which changes the state 'mid-click' and thus triggers your second if block. So you're switching forward then back immediately.

If that's your complete code - your button background by default is set to be 'Transparent' with the form, which will cause it to be transparent once you change the form's transparency. You need to set a background/foreground color for the button.

You've also got a few redundant statements as well.

This should be the cleaned up version of what you need:

```
   if (button3.Text == "Transparent")
   {
      button3.Text = "Black";
      button3.BackColor = Color.Black;
      button3.ForeColor = Color.White;
      this.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
      this.Opacity = 0.7;
      this.TransparencyKey = Color.LimeGreen;
   }
   else if (button3.Text == "Black")
   {
      button3.Text = "Transparent";
      button3.BackColor = Color.Black;
      button3.ForeColor = Color.White;
      this.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
      this.Opacity = 1.0;
      this.TransparencyKey = Color.LimeGreen;
   }
```

Assuming buttons initial text is already set to `Black` or `Transparent` - on click the form goes transparent, button stays visible, and it switches between the two 'states' when clicked.